# R: Efficient column subtraction in a sparse matrix

Tags: r, performance, sparse-matrix, subtraction

In this sparse matrix

```
library(Matrix)
m <- matrix(c(1,3,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,1,1,2), nrow = 6)
M <- sparseMatrix(i = m[,1], j = m[,2], x = m[,3], dimnames = list(expression(x1, x2, x3), expression(t1, t2, t3, t4)))
M
3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   t1 t2 t3 t4
x1  1  2  .  .
x2  .  1  1  .
x3  1  .  .  2
```

how can I most efficiently subtract the value at t-1 from the value at t?

It is possible this way, storing the result in matrix D:

```
D <- Matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(expression(x1, x2, x3), expression(t1, t2, t3, t4)))
for(i in 2:4){
    D[,i] <- M[,i]-M[,(i-1)]
}
D
3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   t1 t2 t3 t4
x1  .  1 -2  .
x2  .  1  . -1
x3  . -1  .  2
```

But is this the most efficient way?

Maybe it is more efficient using the summary m?

P.S.: D[2,3] would ideally read "0" instead of ".". How can I obtain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to `cbind` first empty column:

```
empty_col_1 <- Matrix(0, nrow = nrow(M), ncol = 1, 
                      dimnames = list(NULL, "t1"))
D <- cbind(empty_col_1, M[, -1] - M[, -ncol(M)])
```

Comment: Better, you got the `0` that I lost in the assignment :) Still an R beginner, `cbind` looks useful.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy and Joachim, your solution is 8 x faster than my loop.

Comment: Will do, just wanted to wait if someone comes up with something even better.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably shortcuts, but one way is to create an empty sparse matrix of the correct size;

```
> D = Matrix(0, dim(M)[1], dim(M)[2], sparse=TRUE, dimnames=dimnames(M))

# 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#    t1 t2 t3 t4
# x1  .  .  .  .
# x2  .  .  .  .
# x3  .  .  .  .
```

...and populate it with the difference;

```
> D[,2:ncol(D)] = M[,2:ncol(M)] - M[,1:ncol(M)-1]

# 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#    t1 t2 t3 t4
# x1  .  1 -2  .
# x2  .  1  . -1
# x3  . -1  .  2
```